# Unable to retrieve the list of workspaces. Error: Insufficient privileges

Tags: watson-conversation

Why do i get this error message when i try to launch conversation service tool:

> Unable to retrieve the list of workspaces. Error: Insufficient privileges

Answer (score 2):

You need delete cookies of your browser. I faced with the same problem but after to delete cookies I could see my workspaces.

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the developers of the Watson Conversation service and you seem to have uncovered a small bug in the way that the tooling currently operates. We've been able to successfully reproduce this.

In short, when you open up the tooling to train an instance of the Watson Conversation service a call is made to Bluemix for all instances of the Watson Conversation service that you can see. However, due to the way that Bluemix space permissions work, you may be able to see instances that you don't have permission to edit. You should be able to find your service in the dropdown in the upper right corner of the screen.

In order to have permission to edit and make changes to an instance of the Watson Conversation service, you'll need to have `dev` permissions in the space that contains the instance of the Watson Conversation service. If you'd like to work on that service instance, you'll need to ask the person who owns the service instance to grant you `dev` permissions in the space. You can find out more about how to do this in the [managing team members and roles section of the IBM Bluemix documentation](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/admin/users_roles.html).

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue 
"Unable to retrieve the list of workspaces. Error: Insufficient privileges".

I double checked my permissions and validated that I have the admin access to all services in my space.

Then, I switched to a different browser and was able to navigate to the watson tool login page.So for my case, it looks more like a cookie issue. Thanks @Richard L. 's comment.